# VSCode Python Debugger Timeout due to Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode-debugger, debian-buster

I'm running Debian 10 (buster) with a native python installation version 3.7.3.

Currently I'm running a simple test script like

```
def main():
    print(f'\nHello world!\n')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

In VSCode either **Run Python File** and **Debug Python File** work as intended and print the output in the integrated terminal.

After changing the interpreter to Python 3.9.16 however I run into issues.

**Run Python File** still works, but **Debug Python File** throws the error

> Timed out while waiting for debuggee to spawn

with the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/airnd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from debugpy.server import cli
  File "/home/airnd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd  # noqa
  File "/home/airnd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/_vendored/force_pydevd.py", line 40, in <module>
    preimport('pydevd', [
  File "/home/airnd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/_vendored/__init__.py", line 126, in preimport
    import_module(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/airnd/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.4.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_plugins/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'declare_namespace'
```

Versions used:

- VSCode 1.76.0
- vscode-python v2023.4.0
- debugpy 1.6.6
- Python 3.7.3 / Python 3.9.16 (installed via *make altinstall*)

Fixes tried:

- (re-)install setuptools
- use older version of setuptools
- use older version of vscode-python

I'm running out of ideas ...